# Can't call external stylesheet for Wordpress admin (using wp_admin_css)?

Tags: wp-admin, css

I tried the following:

```
<?php

function my_wp_admin_css() {
  echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-content/plugins/custom-admin-style/wp-admin.css" type="text/css" />';
}

add_action('wp_admin_css','my_wp_admin_css');
```

but nothing is being displayed in the Wordpress admin.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `wp_enqueue_style` and hook it into `admin_print_styles`

```
add_action( 'admin_print_styles' , 'my_wp_admin_css' );

function my_wp_admin_css() {

      wp_enqueue_style('my_admin_style' , WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/myPlugin/stylesheet.css' );
}
```

If you just want the stylesheet on your plugins page you can use:

```
$mypage = add_management_page( 'myplugin', 'myplugin', 9, __FILE__, 'myplugin_admin_page' );
add_action( "admin_print_styles-$mypage", 'myplugin_admin_head' );
 
function myplugin_admin_head() {
    // what your plugin needs in its <head>
}
```